# Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu2enc.def' not found

Tags: errors, xetex, texmaker, ubuntu

I got this error while running my tex file in `XeLaTeX`.

For recovering this i install fonts by running following code :

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

But the same error after installing.

The error message is :

```
! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu2enc.def' not found.
(fontenc) You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
```

---

```
Using App : TeXMaker
OS        : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks.. How can i solve this issue..?

Comment: Does installing the following work? `sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex`

Comment: You probably shouldn't be loading `fontenc` if you are using XeLaTeX. Perhaps you meant to load `fontspec` instead?

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that I'm not loading fontenc, just fontspec. I don't have xetex installed because I use lualatex. Strangely, installing `texlive-xetex` also fixed my issue. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the package `eu2enc.def` is installed. In Ubuntu, it is part of the `texlive-xetex` package. Otherwise, you can install it using the texlive manager:

```
tlmgr install euenc
```

You could also try to install the package manually although I would not recommend it. The sources can be found [here](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/euenc).

Comment: I'm using Fedora and I already have the texlive-xetex and texlive-euenc packages installed, however I still get this error.