# Converting a text file into a .tex file using C++

Tags: text-manipulation

I have a text file which contains data like this:

```
word: 'Swine';      conf: 92.03;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'152', X2:'283', Y1: '166', Y2: '202
word: 'flu';    conf: 93.43;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'299', X2:'354', Y1: '164', Y2: '202
word: 'tightens';   conf: 90.12;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'370', X2:'551', Y1: '164', Y2: '211
word: 'its';    conf: 96.04;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'568', X2:'617', Y1: '166', Y2: '202
word: 'grip';   conf: 90.41;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'632', X2:'716', Y1: '166', Y2: '211
word: 'over';   conf: 94.29;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'732', X2:'831', Y1: '175', Y2: '202
word: 'India';      conf: 94.00;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'848', X2:'953', Y1: '164', Y2: '202
```

With the following meanings:

```
Word: Actual word to be printed
Pointsize : Font size
Font name: Name of font used
X1,X2,Y1,Y2: Coordinates of location of word in the document
```

I want to take all this data, and put it as it is in a latex document. Now, I know I have to make a C++ code for this, by first opening a .tex file and start writing down the data by reading from the text file. The problem I am facing is, how to set the exact fonts and size of the text as mentioned in the file? Thanks!

Edit: Finally, I want to make a pdf file from the generated .tex file using the terminal commands. 
Also, I referred the link: `https://priyankacool10.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/creating-tex-file-using-c-program/` and I just need to know, what all do I have to write as part of my C++ code in order to make the .tex file. 
I am not asking for the entire C++ code, just the exact syntax and package details for the same.

Sample Output:

[image]

Edit2: I will need a C++ code for reading the input words from the text file and writing it into a tex file. Is their any other way of doing it?

Edit3: (Error)

```
* Redefining document command \oldstylenums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 128.
*************************************************
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-luatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty

! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `eu2enc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

See the fontenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.99 \ProcessOptions*
```

Comment: How should one interpret an integer as "a location where word is located", or is that irrelevant to the formatting?

Comment: @MikeRenfro, yes that is irrelevant to the formatting needed.

Comment: Do you mean, you want the conversion to do something like `pointsize:'48'` to turn into (say) `\fontsize{48}{72}\selectfont` and you just don't know the LaTeX commands for font stuff?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you want the generated tex file to do? Do you just want to print a list of words in a list, or is the intention that these words occur in some other context and if they do, the specified font should be used? Also if using system fonts like Verdana it would be much easier to use xetex or luatex than pdftex, is that an option? And why is it tagged biblatex?

Comment: I mean, how do I add it to my C++ code and what will things I will have to write as part of my c++ code? I know how to scan text. For example, I was going through the following link : `https://priyankacool10.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/creating-tex-file-using-c-program/` and she has written all the proper syntax for that package. What do I need to use exactly?

Comment: C++ is off topic for this site, clarifying the latex text to generate is on topic but can not be answered unless you give a hint about what the latex is supposed to do,

Comment: Your edit doesn't clarify it at all, sorry. what do you want the pdf to look like? which of the words in your text file should appear in the  pdf and which formatting should be applied to them. just mock up the output in Word or something and post the desired output for the input file (I can't see why C++ would be needed at all)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, check my edit once. Hopefully it will make things more clear.

Comment: Can you clarify the location, where/how the words are placed? An "area" is the space, which is used by the word, but the area is independent from the location.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I have edited the post to include the location of the word specifying the X and Y coordinates.

Comment: You need two coordinates of location of the word in the document. Why there are four coordinates? We are living in a four-dimensional world?

Comment: @wipet, the two pairs of coordinates basically tell you the coordinates of the bounding box around that particular word which they are associated with.

Comment: What's the need for TeX here? As you seem to want arbitrary positioning of individual words in a PDF, wouldn't it be more usual to simply use a suitable PDF library directly?

Comment: @JosephWright, will that PDF Library help me to set the different fonts of words as well as their sizes and locations? If yes, that will be amazing.

Comment: BoundingBox is irrelevant here. TeX is able to calculate it if needed. What you will do if coordinates of BoundingBox given in your file doesn't correspond to the real BoundingBox?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that TeX can read the file directly, I don't think you need C++

[image]

If your input text is `text1.txt` then the above is made by the following tex, processed by xelatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\newread\dfile
\openin\dfile=text1.txt

\def\printword#1: '#2'#3pointsize:'#4'#5font_name:'#6'#7\relax{%
\fontsize{#4}{\numexpr#4+6\relax}\selectfont\dofont{#6}#2 }

\def\dofont#1{\csname do #1\endcsname}
\expandafter\def\csname do Verdana_Bold\endcsname{\bfseries\fontspec{Verdana}}

\def\partest{\par}
\begin{document}

\raggedright
\loop
\ifeof\dfile\else
\read\dfile to \tmp
\ifx\tmp\partest
\par
\else
\expandafter\printword\tmp\relax
\fi
\repeat


\end{document}
```

---

With the new question and new data file you want to use picture mode

[image]

This does what asked although the coordinates seem rather close for 48pt text?

The font could be scaled to a proportion (say half) of the specified size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\textwidth60cm
\pdfpagewidth80cm

\makeatletter
\newread\dfile
\openin\dfile=text2.txt

\def\printword#1: '#2'#3pointsize:'#4'#5font_name:'#6'#7\relax{%
\edef\tmp{\zap@space#7 \@empty}%
\expandafter\getcoords\tmp\relax
{\fontsize{#4}{\numexpr#4+6\relax}\selectfont\dofont{#6}#2}}

\def\dofont#1{\csname do #1\endcsname}
\expandafter\def\csname do Verdana_Bold\endcsname{\bfseries\fontspec{Verdana}}

\def\getcoords#1X1:'#2'#3Y1:'#4'#5\relax{%
\typeout{#2/#4}%
\put(#2,4)}
\def\partest{\par}
\begin{document}

\hspace*{-10cm}\begin{picture}(200,200)
\loop
\ifeof\dfile\else
\read\dfile to \tmp
\ifx\tmp\partest
\par
\else
\expandafter\printword\tmp\relax
\fi
\repeat
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if my input file contains the exact location of the words in terms of `x` and `y` coordinates, how can I incorporate that in this code?

Comment: That's why I repeatedly asked under the question for you to say what you wanted the latex to do, what part of the text file should be typeset. You can put the loop inside a `picture` environment, and then use `\put(x,y){...}` to position the text by coordinate.

Comment: I am sorry for not able to get you properly earlier. Can you tell me in the above code how do I do this specifically? I am relatively new to Latex. Also, I think the above code will work only for Verdana Bold. But if the font of different words is different, how do I introduce a placeholder sort of thing for font? For ex, if it sees some other font, it writes that particular word in that font.

Comment: @John No it will work for any font you just need to add a line like  `\expandafter\def\csname do Verdana_Bold\endcsname{\bfseries\fontspec{Verdana}}` to map the names used in your file to the system font name. I added a picture mode version using coordinates

Comment: thanks a ton for the extended help. Just one small thing regarding the font thing, if the input text file contains word with different fonts, let's assume `Verdana` for the first word and `Comic Sans` for the second word, will I have to include the above statement for every font? Or will the above code automatically replace the font name picked up from the text file into the above statement?

Comment: please let me know how if the file has multiple fonts, will the above code handle the variation?

Comment: @John yes font is set for each word

Answer (score 4):

I know, Python is not C++, but I wanted some exercise in this language.

The specified font size and the area locations do not fit too well, even
if the font size would be scaled down by around 75%. Therefore I have used `\resizebox` to force the text to the size of the specified area location.
The word is placed via `\put` of the `picture` environment. There are more
powerful environments for drawings like TikZ or `pstricks`. But advanced features are not needed here and `picture` is much more efficient and faster.

The coordinates are transformed, since the vertical axis has the opposite
direction of the y values need for the `picture` environment. The program
calculates the minimum and maximum values and sets the lower left corner
as new origin.

Before the word is set, the program sets some lines to show the specified
rectangle.

The Python program can be called with the text file name as argument. Without argument, the text data are taken from the standard input. Output is standard output, which can be redirected to a TeX file.

The font and size settings are optimized, thus that the font is only defined
once. Also the font is only set for a word, if the font has changed.

The generated file is processed with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX because of package `fontspec`. Then it is easier to use arbitrary font names, as long as LuaTeX or XeTeX know, where to find them.

Some characters need special treatment in TeX, see the program code for an example, how to deal with these characters.

A little more elegant would be to put the TeX preamble into a new LaTeX class
file. Then the generated TeX file would just contain `\documentclass{...}` as whole preamble.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput;
import re;

line_pattern = re.compile(
        r"word:\s*'(?P<word>[^']+)';\s*"
        r"conf:\s*[0-9\.]+;\s*"
        r"pointsize:\s*'(?P<pointsize>\d+)':,"
        r"font_name:\s*'(?P<font_name>[^']+)',\s*"
        r"X1:\s*'(?P<X1>\d+)',\s*"
        r"X2:\s*'(?P<X2>\d+)',\s*"
        r"Y1:\s*'(?P<Y1>\d+)',\s*"
        r"Y2:\s*'(?P<Y2>\d+)'\s*")

# Mapping from character to TeX representation
tex_char_map = {}
for c in "%#$&":
    tex_char_map[c] = "\\" + c
for c in "_^~\\{}":
    tex_char_map[c] = r"\symbol{" + str(ord(c)) + "}"

fonts = set()
words = []
x_min = None
x_max = None
y_min = None
y_max = None

for line in fileinput.input():
    match = line_pattern.match(line)
    if match:
        word = match.group("word")
        pointsize = match.group("pointsize")
        font_name = match.group("font_name")
        X1 = int(match.group("X1"))
        X2 = int(match.group("X2"))
        Y1 = int(match.group("Y1"))
        Y2 = int(match.group("Y2"))
        fonts.add(font_name)
        data = (word, pointsize, font_name, X1, X2, Y1, Y2)
        words.append(data)
        # assuming X1 <= X2 and Y1 <= Y2
        if x_min is None or X1 < x_min:
            x_min = X1
        if x_max is None or X2 > x_max:
            x_max = X2
        if y_min is None or Y1 < y_min:
            y_min = Y1
        if y_max is None or Y2 > y_max:
            y_max = Y2

tex_preamble = r"""\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\NewFont}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newfontfamily\csname#1\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\SetFont}[1]{%
  \csname#1\endcsname
  \ignorespaces
}
\newdimen\FontSize
\newdimen\FontUnitLength
\setlength{\FontUnitLength}{.75bp}
\newcommand*{\SetSize}[1]{%
  \setlength{\FontSize}{#1\FontUnitLength}%
  \fontsize{\FontSize}{1.2\FontSize}\selectfont
  \ignorespaces
}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Put}{}
\def\Put(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5{%
  \put(#1,#2){\line(1,0){#3}\line(0,1){#4}}%
  \put(#1,#2){\line(0,1){#4}}%
  \put(#1,#2){\put(0,#4){\line(1,0){#3}}}%
  %\put(#1,#2){\makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{\resizebox{#3\unitlength}{!}{#5}}}%
  \put(#1,#2){%
    \makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{%
      \resizebox{#3\unitlength}{#4\unitlength}{%
        \raisebox{\depth}{#5}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  %\put(#1,#2){\makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{#5}}%
}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}"""
print(tex_preamble)

for font in fonts:
    print(r"\NewFont{" + font + "}")

print(r"\begin{document}")

picture_width = x_max - x_min
picture_height = y_max - y_min
print(r"\begin{picture}(%d,%d)" % (picture_width, picture_height))

current_font = ""
current_pointsize = ""
for word, pointsize, font_name, X1, X2, Y1, Y2 in words:
    if font != current_font:
        print(r"\SetFont{" + font + "}")
        current_font = font

    if pointsize != current_pointsize:
        print(r"\SetSize{" + pointsize + "}")
        current_pointsize = pointsize

    w = ""
    for c in word:
        if c in tex_char_map:
            w += tex_char_map[c]
        else:
            w += c
    width = X2 - X1
    height = Y2 - Y1
    x = X1 - x_min
    y = picture_height - (Y2 - y_min)
    print(r"\Put(%d,%d)(%d,%d){%s}" % (x, y, width, height, w))

print(r"\end{picture}")

print(r"\end{document}")
```

The input data (with closing single quote added for the value of `Y2`):

```
word: 'Swine';      conf: 92.03;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'152', X2:'283', Y1: '166', Y2: '202'
word: 'flu';    conf: 93.43;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'299', X2:'354', Y1: '164', Y2: '202'
word: 'tightens';   conf: 90.12;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'370', X2:'551', Y1: '164', Y2: '211'
word: 'its';    conf: 96.04;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'568', X2:'617', Y1: '166', Y2: '202'
word: 'grip';   conf: 90.41;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'632', X2:'716', Y1: '166', Y2: '211'
word: 'over';   conf: 94.29;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'732', X2:'831', Y1: '175', Y2: '202'
word: 'India';      conf: 94.00;pointsize:'48':,font_name:'Verdana_Bold',X1:'848', X2:'953', Y1: '164', Y2: '202'
```

The generated LaTeX file:

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newcommand*{\NewFont}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newfontfamily\csname#1\endcsname{#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\SetFont}[1]{%
  \csname#1\endcsname
  \ignorespaces
}
\newdimen\FontSize
\newdimen\FontUnitLength
\setlength{\FontUnitLength}{.75bp}
\newcommand*{\SetSize}[1]{%
  \setlength{\FontSize}{#1\FontUnitLength}%
  \fontsize{\FontSize}{1.2\FontSize}\selectfont
  \ignorespaces
}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\Put}{}
\def\Put(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5{%
  \put(#1,#2){\line(1,0){#3}\line(0,1){#4}}%
  \put(#1,#2){\line(0,1){#4}}%
  \put(#1,#2){\put(0,#4){\line(1,0){#3}}}%
  %\put(#1,#2){\makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{\resizebox{#3\unitlength}{!}{#5}}}%
  \put(#1,#2){%
    \makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{%
      \resizebox{#3\unitlength}{#4\unitlength}{%
        \raisebox{\depth}{#5}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  %\put(#1,#2){\makebox(#3,#4)[lb]{#5}}%
}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}
\NewFont{Verdana_Bold}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(801,47)
\SetFont{Verdana_Bold}
\SetSize{48}
\Put(0,9)(131,36){Swine}
\Put(147,9)(55,38){flu}
\Put(218,0)(181,47){tightens}
\Put(416,9)(49,36){its}
\Put(480,0)(84,45){grip}
\Put(580,9)(99,27){over}
\Put(696,9)(105,38){India}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: No python3? still not hanging out with the cool guys eh? :D

Comment: @percusse Fixed, you can now use python3.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, so I ran the python code that you supplied on my original text input file (with proper single quotes around Y2), and it generated the .tex file. Post that, I am trying to convert the .tex file generated into a PDF (which was my final goal), but it gives the following error `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./abc.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \NeedsTeXFormat
                   {LaTeX2e}`

Comment: @John The purpose of `\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}` is that the macro name is program. You need LaTeX, not plain TeX for a LaTeX file. Also LuaTeX or XeTeX are required because of package `fontspec` and the non-TeX-Font `Verdana_Bold`. Try `lualatex abc` or `xelatex abc`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, so I tried the `lualtex abc` step. It asked me to download the `lualatex` package and I did that. On then executing the command, now it gives the error (exact error mentioned as part of the original post, see edit). I tried to search for what causes the fontec error, and found this, `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219622/package-fontenc-error-encoding-file-eu2enc-def-not-found`. I tried `tlmgr install eunec` but it doesn't let me install that and gives the error `(running on Debian,switching to user mode!) cannot setup TLPDB in /home/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.`

Comment: @John This is a different question about installation issues with LuaTeX (MWE, e.g.: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fontspec}\begin{document}Hello World!\end{document}`. An alternative is XeTeX (`xelatex`).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, finally it worked. Thanks a lot! But it still misses out on some fonts and shows they aren't present, I don't know why. I will try searching more for the solution. Though I just wanted to know is their any way I can remove the box surrounding the words? Is that possible?

Comment: @John Remove or comment the lines containing `\line`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, you mean I should remove the following lines from the tex file completely `\put(#1,#2){\line(1,0){#3}\line(0,1){#4}}%
  \put(#1,#2){\line(0,1){#4}}%
  \put(#1,#2){\put(0,#4){\line(1,0){#3}}}%`? All of these are written where you have defined the put command.

Comment: @John, yes these lines are responsible for putting the lines of the rectangle.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I just wanted to know one last thing. If let's say I have images saved in EPS/JPEG/PNG Format on my system, along with their coordinates (just like I had for the words), how can I integrate them in the latex code above? What will be the process for that? Thanks!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, please let me know how can I integrate the pictures into a latex file? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @John, images are included via package `graphicx` by the command `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, how do I exactly specify the coordinates (like they are specified for text) for the images in the latex file?

Comment: @John For example, `\put(<x>, <y>){\includegraphics[width=<width>, height=<height>]{<image file>}}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, your command doesn't seem to work. It gives the following error, `Runaway argument?
4){\makebox (15,7)[lb]{\resizebox {15\unitlength }{7\unitlength }{\raisebox \ETC
.
! File ended while scanning use of \Put.
<inserted text> 
\par 
<*> abc
`

Comment: @John The example does work without error. Your error message looks like a syntax error such as forgotten comma.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I am talking about when I am trying to add a picture. What code did you run (while including the picture)? Can you post it here once? (Assuming I have the top left (x1,y1) and the bottom right (x2,y2) coordinates for the picture.)

Comment: @John Check for a simple syntax error. The parameter text of `\Put` is `(#1,#2)(#3,#4)#5`. The parentheses and commas has to be present and must not be omitted or hidden inside macros. If you can't find the error, then post a minimal example.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, I just want to know the macro you made for `put` takes in `2` sets of points, but which points do they refer to exactly? Are they diagonally opposite points for a picture?

Comment: @John `(#1,#2)` is the lower left corner and `(#3,#4)` is the width and height.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, So, should I write the command like this? `\Put(415,1414)(515,243){\includegraphics[width=515pt, height=243pt]{/home/John/Desktop/2.jpg}}`,i.e. do I have to mention width and height two times, one inside includegraphichs and one as part of Put command?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, so, I was using the script you provided as an answer. However, I am facing a problem. Though your code detects multiple fonts and set them using `newfonts` at the beginning of the .tex file, however, when it writes actual words using the put command, it uses only a single font and not the different fonts which might have been there in the original file. How do I do that?

Comment: `\newfont` defines a new font, the macro is then used to select the font for the following text (in the same scope).